# Looking for Grinch Heart Attack Video on YouTube

Tags: story-identification, dr-seuss

So, I don't remember the name of the video, but I remember a live-action parody of Dr. Seuss' How the Grinch Stole Christmas that was a parody of the heart growing 3 sizes too big scene.

In this scene, it is instead revealed that the Grinch is having a heart attack.

However, I cannot find the video again. Can someone help?

Comment: Was this referencing the cartoon? The live-action (CGI, really) adaptation?

Comment: I think it was meant to parody the Jim Carrey film, the costume and visuals looked closest to that version

Comment: And are you certain you don't mean the existing live action film at http://thecaringcatalyst.com/a-necessary-heart-attack/

Comment: Yes. There's an existing heart disease where the heart grows bigger and is actually much deadlier than what was in the film.

Comment: Something like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aimjAkBIEg ?

Comment: No, although still quite humorous. The way the parody happens, it shows the scene as normal, before he starts feeling pain. I think there's a young Cindy Lou Who as well and I think a scene where they have to inject a needle into his chest

Comment: This one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8J-YmVs1j0 ?

Comment: No, that's just the regular scene from the Jim Carrey film, where he thinks he's having a heart attack. The parody scene is live action and he is having an actual heart attack. I think it ends with him in a hospital bed

Comment: Do you refer to this one https://themq.org/2019/12/articles/news/actor-dies-of-cardiac-arrest-in-scene-where-grinchs-heart-grows-three-sizes/#:~:text=Seuss'%20%E2%80%9CHow%20the%20Grinch%20Stole,musical%20about%20American%20history%20was.%E2%80%9D ?

Comment: + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcwsRApnyso

Comment: No, not that one.

Comment: I have found a number of  cartoon panels with this joke. I've been unable to export any, due to lack of permission.

Comment: It was a live action parody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Studio C skit "How the Grinch Hijacked the Holidays" matches your description.  (Note: Thanks to Laurel whose edit was basically the entire detailed answer and a link to a better version of the video.)

> His heart grew three sizes, but that was one size too much.
> "My blood isn't flowing.
> A doc needs to pump it."
> So, we called 911 to come to Mount Crumpit.
> "Help, my heart's beating fast and I feel I can't breathe."
> "You have hypertrophic cardiomyopathy."

Comment: Yes, this is it. Honestly, I was beginning to wonder if I was experiencing some kind of Mandela Effect or dream, this is NOT an easy video to find

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this:

It was published by WhoRangTheBell.com a comedy website

Comment: No, it was already asked, take a look at the comments above.

Comment: No, not this one, it was a live-action spoof of the Jim Carrey version